# Checking if GET variable is set checking the value does not work

Tags: php

```
<?php               
if((isset($_GET["r"])) == "en")
{
    echo "<font color='#FF9900'>Right.</font>";
}
else
{
    echo "";
}
?>
```

When "index.php?r=en" it shows right. But also when I send a wrong value, it shows the same result. like "index.php?r=abc" or "index.php?r".

How to solve this?

Comment: `isset` returns `true` or `false`.

Comment: This site is not designed for these kinds of questions.  You should ask specific questions that reflect the research you have done so far, and where you have become stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
if((isset($_GET["r"])) == "en")
```

with

```
if((isset($_GET["r"])) && $_GET["r"] == "en")
```

Answer (score 3):

`isset($_GET["r"])` is a boolean operator. When this is true you're doing the following comparison:

`if(true == "en") ...`

What you want is:

```
if( !empty($_GET[r]) && $_GET[r] == 'en' ) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( isset($_GET["r"]) &&  $_GET["r"] == "en")
{
    echo "<font color='#FF9900'>Right.</font>";
}
else
{
    echo "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(isset($_GET['r'])){      

     if($get === 'en'){
         echo 'something';}
       else {
         echo 'nothing';}
    }
```

Comment: Yea.. .but I wouldn't use a switch for only one case... That's what an `if` statement is for.

Comment: Yea, but I assumed that he might want to extend the list, since it seems like he is creating a language or something similar.

Comment: That's also true... With a little more explanation, your post would be the best suggestion really...

Comment: Toobad, you convinced me to change it :) @Lix

Comment: at least fix the formatting then :P

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(true === array_key_exists('r', $_GET) && 'en' == $_GET['r'])
{
    echo "<font color='#FF9900'>Right.</font>";
}
else
{
    echo "";
}
?>
```